# GPUImageView with Glide

Tags: java, android, gpuimage

I am trying to implement an Android image filter library called [GPUImageView](https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage).

I have tried to use it like in the below code:

```
 public static GPUImageView img_bg;
 img_bg = (GPUImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_bg);
 categoryAdapter1.setOnClickLIstner(new OnClickLIstner() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v, Image image, int pos) {
                            Glide.with(NameArt.this)
                                    .load(image.getDrawableId())
                                    .centerCrop()
                                    .dontAnimate()
                                    .into(img_bg);
                            img_bg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    });
```

But I am getting an error:

> cannot resolve method 'into' (`jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage.GPUImageView`)

Does anyone know how to resolve this? Thanks

Comment: You are loading  non image, GPUImage is not extended from imageView Class. `.into(*/here should be image*/)`

Comment: @Ibrahim I am loading image from adapter...please check .load. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`GPUImageView` is not a subclass of ImageView. Write a custom subclass of `com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target` that overrides `onResourceReady` to call `GPUImageView::setImage(Bitmap)`

Comment: Note that you'll probably also want to tell Glide that you want it as a Bitmap use `asBitmap()`.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for suggestion. I have started learning java yet...can You please explain your answer littler more ?

Answer (score 0):

This Will help you to solve that problem.

```
  Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load( IMAGE )
            .asBitmap()
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                    BITMAP= resource;
                }
            });
```

and compile version of glide below.

```
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

Comment: Hello thanks for suggestion....I am not able to reslove method called .asBitmap() and can you please describe what is BITMAP= resource; Thanks

Comment: than you need to compile other version of glide
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

Comment: what is BITMAP= resource;

Answer (score 0):

As previously stated, GPUImageView is not a subclass of ImageView. with Glide 4.9.0 and GPUImage 2.0.4,

add on your layout

```
    <jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage.GPUImageView
    android:id="@+id/picture_player"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:gpuimage_show_loading="false"
    app:gpuimage_surface_type="texture_view"
    />
```

and in your code:

```
            val pp = findViewById<GPUImageView>(R.id.picture_player)

        Glide.with(this).asBitmap()
            .load(uri)
            .into(object : CustomViewTarget<GPUImageView, Bitmap>(pp) {
                override fun onResourceReady(
                    resource: Bitmap,
                    transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?
                ) {
                    pp.setImage(resource)
                }

                override fun onLoadFailed(errorDrawable: Drawable?) {
                    //TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
                }

                override fun onResourceCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {
                    //TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
                }
            })
```